# Calculating the number of paths through graph

Tags: algorithm, graph

I am looking the number of unique *x* length paths through a graph starting at a particular node.

However I have a restriction that no node is visited more than once on any path.

---

For example take the following graph:
[image]

If I am after the number of 3 length paths starting at 5.

The answer would be 9.

```
5 -> 2 -> 1 -> 3
5 -> 2 -> 4 -> 3
5 -> 2 -> 4 -> 7
5 -> 4 -> 2 -> 1
5 -> 4 -> 3 -> 1
5 -> 4 -> 7 -> 6
5 -> 6 -> 7 -> 4
5 -> 7 -> 4 -> 2
5 -> 7 -> 4 -> 3
```

Note I am only concerted with the answer (9) **not the specific paths**.

---

I have tried using an [adjacency matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix) to the power of *x* to give the number of paths, but I cannot work out how to account for unique node restriction.

I have also tried using a [depth-first search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) but the amount of nodes and size of *x* makes this infeasible.

---

EDIT: Confused DFS with BFS (Thank you Nylon Smile & Nikita Rybak).

Comment: How about depth-limited search? it gives you a better space complexity

Comment: BFS is a pretty basic graph-searching algorithm - seems like it would take a ginormous graph to make it infeasible...  How big is a normal graph (both edges and vertices)?  Also, how is it stored?

Comment: @threenplusone I think you mean DFS, BFS has little use here.

Comment: @Xavier Holt: In my main problem there are approx 1000 nodes, approx 30000 edges and I am after a length of 256. It is stored as an adjacency list & matrix.

Comment: @Nikita Rybak & Nylon Smile: My apologies I did mean depth-first search (limited) not breadth.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is NP-Hard.

Reduction from Hamiltonian Path.

Given a graph whose Hamiltonian Path existence we need to check...

Run your algorithm for each vertex, with a path length n-1. Any non-zero return corresponds to Hamiltonian path and vice versa.

So basically, if you find a polynomial time algorithm to solve your problem, then you have a polynomial time algorithm to solve the Hamiltonian Path problem, effectively proving P=NP!

Note: This assumes x is an input.

If you x was fixed (i.e. independent of the number of vertices in the graph), then you have O(n^x) time algorithms, which is in P, but still pretty impractical for medium sized x.

Comment: Reduction from HP doesn't mean NP-Hard it means NP-complete.

Comment: Is this responsive? Op wants count of n-length simple paths, not existence of Hamiltonians.

Comment: @Saeed: NP-Complete = NP-Hard _AND_ NP. Reduction from HP means NP-Hard. If you want NP-Complete, you also have to prove membership in NP.

Comment: @THomas: Not sure what you mean... If you show that a problem is NP-Hard, you basically rule out efficient algorithms (like polynomial time), given the current state of knowledge.

Comment: @Moron, NP is just for decision problems, see wiki's picture: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-hard, but NP-Hard is for decision problems, search problems, or optimization problems.

Comment: @Saeed: Reduction from HP means NP-Hard, not NP-Complete and you seem to be contradicting yourself. For instance, the problem at hand is not a decision problem...

Comment: @Moron, HP is NP-Complete problem (Also because of this it's NP hard) and reduction from HP first means NP-Complete (and conclusion of this means NP-Hard).

Comment: @Moron: ok, in that case, can you flesh out the reduction a bit? Your answer is extremely terse.

Comment: @Saeed: Reduction from an NP-Complete problem means NP-Hard. Period. If you manage to show that the problem is also in NP, only _then_ it is NP-Complete. Frankly I don't understand what you are trying to say.

Comment: @THomas: I have edited the answer. Hope it is clearer now. Let me know if you need more clarifications.

Comment: @Moron, "Reduction from an NP-Complete problem means NP-Hard." I said this before, don't tell me what I said, I thought this problem is NP-complete, but now I think this is not NP-Complete, but my point is instead of saying problem is NP-Hard (generally) it's better to prove it's NP-Complete (more specific answer), If we can't just proving it's NP-Hard. NP-Hard range is very large (like Halt problem) which are really difficult and no one knows solution for them.

Comment: @Moron, well, it was confusing since the question asked for n-len paths, which is P. Your last statement should come first.

Comment: @Thomas: n is the number of vertices in the graph. x is the length of the path sought. So n-1 length paths is still NP-Hard. It was only later that OP talked about x=256, and that too in the comments! So I chose to add the last few sentences.

Comment: @Saeed: _"Reduction from HP doesn't mean NP-Hard it means NP-complete"_ was your very first comment. Your immediate comment before my comment: _"HP is NP-Complete problem (Also because of this it's NP hard) and reduction from HP first means NP-Complete (and conclusion of this means NP-Hard)"_ which is incorrect. It does not mean NP-COmplete. It means NP-Hard! You have it backwards. btw, it is clear that this problem is in FNP, so talking about halting problem is quite pointless. Anyway, I don't see any value in continuing this discussion further. Please pardon me if I don't respond.

Comment: I agree to finish this discussion, yes my statement was wrong.

Answer (score 3):

This problem is a counting problem in #P (number of solutions) instead of a decision problem in NP (yes or no).

Moron's [reduction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4929090/calculating-the-number-of-paths-through-graph/4929154#4929154) still works to prove the problem is [#P-Complete](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sharp-P-complete) because Hamilton Paths is also #P-complete.

Comment: I don't know if this extra answer is appropriate - I just felt so many of the comments of the other answer were about NP-nitpicking and I didn't want the #P bit to get buried under there.

Comment: +1: I agree it is worth another answer, given the traffic to the other one.