# Efficient algorithm to find all the paths from A to Z?

Tags: java, algorithm

With a set of [random inputs](http://qweop.com/temp/files/routes.text) like this (20k lines):

```
A B
U Z
B A
A C
Z A
K Z
A Q
D A
U K
P U
U P
B Y
Y R
Y U
C R
R Q
A D
Q Z
```

Find all the paths from A to Z.

1. A - B - Y - R - Q - Z
2. A - B - Y - U - Z
3. A - C - R - Q - Z
4. A - Q - Z
5. A - B - Y - U - K - Z

[image]

A location cannot appear more than once in the path, hence `A - B - Y - U - P - U - Z` is not valid.

Locations are named AAA to ZZZ (presented here as A - Z for simplicity) and the input is random in such a way that there may or may not be a location ABC, all locations may be XXX (unlikely), or there may not be a possible path at all locations are "isolated".

Initially I'd thought that this is a variation of the unweighted [shortest path problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_path_problem), but I find it rather different and I'm not sure how does the algorithm there apply here.

My current solution goes like this:

1. Pre-process the list such that we have a hashmap which points a location (left), to a list of locations (right)
2. Create a hashmap to keep track of "visited locations". Create a list to store "found paths".
3. Store X (starting-location) to the "visited locations" hashmap.
4. Search for X in the first hashmap, (Location A will give us (B, C, Q) in O(1) time).
5. For-each found location (B, C, Q), check if it is the final destination (Z). If so store it in the "found paths" list. Else if it doesn't already exist in "visited locations" hashmap, Recurl to step 3 now with that location as "X". (actual code below)

With this current solution, it takes **forever** to map **all** (not shortest) possible routes from "BKI" to "SIN" for [this provided data](http://qweop.com/temp/files/routes.text).

I was wondering if there's a more effective (time-wise) way of doing it. Does anyone know of a better algorithm  to find all the paths from an arbitrary position A to an arbitrary position Z ?

Actual Code for current solution:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Test {
    private static HashMap<String, List<String>> left_map_rights;

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        left_map_rights = new HashMap<>();
        BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("routes.text"));
        String line;
        HashMap<String, Void> lines = new HashMap<>();
        while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
            if (lines.containsKey(line)) { // ensure no duplicate lines
                continue;
            }
            lines.put(line, null);
            int space_location = line.indexOf(' ');
            String left = line.substring(0, space_location);
            String right = line.substring(space_location + 1);
            if(left.equals(right)){ // rejects entries whereby left = right
                continue;
            }
            List<String> rights = left_map_rights.get(left);
            if (rights == null) {
                rights = new ArrayList<String>();
                left_map_rights.put(left, rights);
            }
            rights.add(right);
        }
        r.close();
        System.out.println("start");
        List<List<String>> routes = GetAllRoutes("BKI", "SIN");
        System.out.println("end");
        for (List<String> route : routes) {
            System.out.println(route);
        }
    }

    public static List<List<String>> GetAllRoutes(String start, String end) {
        List<List<String>> routes = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> rights = left_map_rights.get(start);
        if (rights != null) {
            for (String right : rights) {
                List<String> route = new ArrayList<>();
                route.add(start);
                route.add(right);
                Chain(routes, route, right, end);
            }
        }
        return routes;
    }

    public static void Chain(List<List<String>> routes, List<String> route, String right_most_currently, String end) {
        if (right_most_currently.equals(end)) {
            routes.add(route);
            return;
        }
        List<String> rights = left_map_rights.get(right_most_currently);
        if (rights != null) {
            for (String right : rights) {
                if (!route.contains(right)) {
                    List<String> new_route = new ArrayList<String>(route);
                    new_route.add(right);
                    Chain(routes, new_route, right, end);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe this can help you.. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm

Comment: If each line represents a directed edge in a graph, it really is what you though at first, the unweighted shortest path problem. What might be throwing you off is that the data representation is different from the one the Dijkstra algorithm uses. Transform your input and you're good to go

Comment: dijksta's algorithm is for finding shortest path in weighted graph. It doesn't fit here as the graph is neither weighted nor the path OP is looking for has to be the shortest one. He's looking for **all** the paths from A to Z, not the **shortest** one.

Comment: What do the two columns signify?

Comment: i.e for unweighted graph there are simpler (and commonly known) algorithms to find the shortest path from A to Z.

Comment: @ErickRobertson locations, but it's an arbitrary name. from AAA to ZZZ

Comment: @Pacerier. Is the graph acyclic?

Comment: @dario_ramos I mean i'm not looking for an efficient way to find the shortest path, but rather an efficient way to find all the paths (even the longest ones). another requirement was to sort it according to shortest path first, but I was thinking if I could get all the paths, sorting would be easy.

Comment: ok, scratch it I see it's not acyclic

Comment: @soulcheck The left side and right side are totally random. so if you mean whether it will enter an infinite loop, then yes it may so steps must be taken to ensure that "visited locations" are not re-visited.

Comment: 2 more suggestions i would make to your algo - 1. while preprocessing in step 1, do not put keys that have values smaller than the key ( e.g Z -> A), that will cut some load. 2. in visited locations, map the starting location to the paths there on that you find for that location, so you dont have to look them up again.

Comment: @Pacerier: My bad, I missed that. You're right, this is a bit more complex. In that case, uhm's answer is on the mark. A variant of Dijkstra's algorithm is a good starting point

Comment: @Pacerier the question is if your 'all' paths can contain cyclic ones.

Comment: @soulcheck. A location cannot appear more than once in the path, hence A - B - Y - U - P - U - Z is not valid.

Comment: I assume there is more than 26 nodes as this only yields 26 * 25 possible links between paths (650).  How many nodes do you have in your 20K lines example?

Comment: @BartKiers Yes the `A - B - Y - U - K - Z` is valid, but a location cannot appear more than once in the path, otherwise it would be "infinite": A - B - A - B - A - B - A - B - A - B ..

Comment: @PeterLawrey locations are named AAA to ZZZ and the input is random in such a way that there may or may not be a location ABC, all locations may be AAA (unlikely), or there may not be a possible path at all ("isolated locations")

Comment: FYI, the image was generated on [http://graphviz-dev.appspot.com](http://graphviz-dev.appspot.com/) with the source: `digraph g{A->B;U->Z;B->A;A->C;Z->A;K->Z;A->Q;D->A;U->K;P->U;U->P;B->Y;Y->R;Y->U;C->R;R->Q;A->D;Q->Z}`

Comment: @Pacerier: so theoretically your longest path could be 17576 (*i.e.* 26**3) locations, where you'd visit all locations from AAA to ZZZ exactly once?

Comment: @user988052. Yes the theoretical maximum is 26^3: 17576

Comment: You have 17576 nodes, but you only have 20000 links.  You probably have a chance smaller than one in a gazillion that you'll have a connecting path from A to Z.

Comment: **Conversation moved to chat:** http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5501/efficient-algorithm-to-find-all-the-paths-from-a-to-z

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calculating the number of paths through graph](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4929090/calculating-the-number-of-paths-through-graph)

Comment: Sadly, this problem is #P complete

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As I understand your question, Dijkstras algorithm cannot be applied as is, since shortest path problem per definition finds a single path in a set of all possible paths. Your task is to find all paths per-se.

Many optimizations on Dijkstras algorithm involve cutting off search trees with higher costs. You won't be able to cut off those parts in your search, as you need all findings.

And I assume you mean all paths *excluding circles*.

Algorithm:

- Pump network into a 2dim array 26x26 of boolean/integer. fromTo[i,j].
  Set a 1/true for an existing link.
- Starting from the first node trace all following nodes (search links for 1/true).
- Keep visited nodes in a some structure (array/list). Since maximal
  depth seems to be 26, this should be possible via recursion.
- And as @soulcheck has written below, you may think about cutting of paths you have aleady visted. You may keep a list of paths towards the destination in each element of the array. Adjust the breaking condition accordingly.
- Break when

  - visiting the end node (store the result)
  - when visiting a node that has been visted before (circle)
  - visiting a node for which you have already found all paths to the destination and merge your current path with all the existing ones from that node.

Performance wise I'd vote against using hashmaps and lists and prefer static structures.

Hmm, while re-reading the question, I realized that the name of the nodes cannot be limited to A-Z. You are writing something about 20k lines, with 26 letters, a fully connected A-Z network would require far less links. Maybe you skip recursion and static structures :)

Ok, with valid names from AAA to ZZZ an array would become far too large. So you better create a dynamic structure for the network as well. Counter question: regarding performance, what is the best data structure for a less popuplate array as my algorithm would require? I' vote for an 2 dim ArrayList. Anyone?

Comment: A location must not appear more than once in the path, if that's what you mean by *excluding circles*.

Comment: I was wondering if anyone would mention the possibility that some sadistic instructor would include a circle.

Comment: Well, I understand he's telling us to use *backtracking*. It's a very valid answer.

Comment: @uhm However there is no "fixed" locations, in the sense that I do not know how many locations there are in the input which goes from (AAA to ZZZ). Array of 26^6.. 308 915 776

Comment: @uhm one question. How do you define a node for which you have already found all paths to the destination?

Comment: @soulcheck: When the node has no more successors that has not been processed so far, then all possible paths have been found. Assuming that all nodes are traversed in alphabethical order, that means for the example above: Lets say U is processed. Then K is processed (contains a path to Z), then P is processed (no path circle) then Z is processed (contains path to Z); after that all children of U has been processed, thus all possible paths from U to Z have are stored in U.

Comment: @uhm sorry for late response. So, if i understand correctly in case ob complete graph ABCD and query for paths from A to D, what could happen is that the algorithm would descend though path ABCD, recorded C as already processed (cause it has no more successors, and the only one it had was D, so it strores path to D for node C) and later on, when trying to go directly from A to C would reuse that path memoized path and only that path. It's incorrect as there are paths through C that can't be found this way, ie. ACBD.

Comment: Possible paths from node X to destination are dependent on the path already traversed. You can't memoize and reuse them without missing some solutions.

Comment: @uhm to be frank I've tried creating an array of 400million booleans and there's no OOM for me. Btw will you think a bit-vector/bitset would be more efficient?

Comment: @soulcheck: I see your point. You must not count nodes as successfully visted (thus include them in the break condition) when they would produce a circle. Only nodes whose child nodes (and their children and so forth) have been completely visited (there is a path to the destination or there is no path) may contribute. All other nodes have to be visited again later. I will incorporate all the comments inthe answer in a few days.

Comment: @Pacerier: I think that it is best to have a 2dim array that represents an in general densly popuplated adjacent matrix (no Arraylists, they are not necessary, I got drawn away on the actual demands for the data structure - memory is an issue, but you are not dynamically adding nodes, so a previously fixed 2dim array is sufficient). That 2dim array of simple objects should contain enought information in order to immediately determine whether all children have been successfully visited (path/no path) or not plus the paths for those which provide a route to the destination.

Comment: This answer has many upvotes, but it's completely unclear what the algorithm is or if it's correct. Is it BFS or DFS? When "visiting a node for which you have already found all paths to the destination and merge your current path with all the existing ones from that node" how do you avoid adding paths that include the same nodes twice?

Answer (score 7):

What you're proposing is a scheme for DFS, only with backtracking.It's correct, unless you want to permit cyclic paths (you didn't specify if you do).

There are two gotchas, though.

1. You have to keep an eye on nodes you already visited on current path (to eliminate cycles)
2. You have to know how to select next node when backtracking, so that you don't descend on the same subtree in the graph when you already visited it on the current path.

The pseudocode is more or less as follows:

```
getPaths(A, current_path) :
    if (A is destination node): return [current_path]
    for B = next-not-visited-neighbor(A) : 
        if (not B already on current path) 
            result = result + getPaths(B, current_path + B)
    return result 

 list_of_paths =  getPaths(A, [A])
```

which is almost what you said.

Be careful though, as finding all paths in complete graph is pretty time and memory consuming.

**edit**
For clarification, the algorithm has Ω(n!) time complexity in worst case, as it has to list all paths from one vertex to another in complete graph of size n, and there are at least (n-2)! paths of form <A, permutations of all nodes except A and Z, Z>. No way to make it better if only listing the result would take as much.

Comment: Hey thanks for the help, btw initially I'd thought that there's already an established algorithm (like possibly a "all-paths problem algorithm") but looks like there isn't one already out there.

Comment: it's just such a small deviance from normal DFS that it doesn't have it's own name (i think) ;)

Comment: Would you propose a DFS with break as the best solution for this problem?

Comment: @Pacerier i'm not sure about the last condition uhm proposed. It's difficult to tell whether you found all paths to the destination node from the current one during the algorithm run. It's very visible in case of complete graphs where calculading all paths from all nodes is equivalent so you cant really tell if you did it or not. But the general idea is correct.

Comment: however my current implementation (as shown in the edit) takes **forever** to run, are you aware if it could be fixed to perform better ?

Comment: it can't. It's Ω(n!) in worst case (that is a complete graph, where you have at least n-2! paths from one vertex to another and you have to list them all)

Comment: but it's so horrible that it didn't even complete the outermost loop **once**, `for (String right : rights) {`, and it's still running..

Comment: make sure you implemented it right. take a look at existing DFS implementation and adjust them to your needs. Since it's homework I can't really help you more. Just don't be surprised it's slow. It's supposed to be.

Comment: ok, but since it's working with small inputs (like the example in the question), I'm sure it's *right* though probably not optimal

Comment: @Pacerier: you're doing a lot of unnecessary copying of the route ArrayList, with a little bit of clever thinking you can make it such that you only need to copy the ArrayList when you found a completed path. Also, it might be possible to reduce the O(n) check for membership test for the new_route to O(1) if you use ListOrderedSet (a Set that maintains sorting order, which has O(1) for .add(), .remove(), and .contains()); try LinkedHashSet.

Comment: @LieRyan hey thanks for the help =D Btw for the membership test would a normal HashMap suffice (since `containsKey` is `O(1)` as well) ?

Comment: @Pacerier: HashMap doesn't retain any ordering; using ListOrderedSet is one way, another alternative is to use a List and a HashSet to store the current route and the membership test in two data structure.

Comment: @LieRyan sry I'm not following you.. why do we need to retain the ordering of the collection of visited locations when we are only interested in finding out if a location X exists within that collection?

Comment: @Pacerier: Going from A -> B -> C -> Z would be considered a different path than going from A -> C -> B -> Z, therefore a route must be ordered. The ListOrderedSet will double as the current "trace" (`route`/`new_route` in your code) and for fast membership test. If you're using ArrayList like the current code, you don't have a fast membership test; but if you're using HashSet you can't distinguish the case when A -> B -> C -> Z and A -> C -> B -> Z.

Answer (score 1):

Your data is essentially an [adjacency list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_list) which allows you to construct a tree rooted at the node corresponding to A. In order to obtain all the paths between A & Z, you can run any tree traversal algorithm.

Of course, when you're building the tree you have to ensure that you don't introduce cycles.

Comment: But the source data is a possibly cyclic graph, not a tree. Looking for all paths in a tree wouldn't be useful anyway, as there would be exactly one path between each pair of vertices.

Comment: @interjay: No ; that's true for free trees not for a directed tree.

Comment: According to Wikipedia's definition of a directed tree (a directed graph which would be a tree if the directions on the edges were ignored), there would still be at most 1 path between nodes. Suppose you have a complete graph with four nodes A,B,C,D and all possible edges between them, and you want to find all paths from A to D. What would your tree look like?

Answer (score 1):

I would proceed recursively where I would build a list of all possible paths between **all** pairs of nodes.

I would start by building, for all pairs (X, Y), the list L_2(X, Y) which is the list of paths of length 2 that go from X to Y; that's trivial to build since that's the input list you are given.

Then I would build the lists L_3(X, Y), recursively, using the known lists L_2(X, Z) and L_2(Z, Y), looping over Z.  For example, for (C, Q), you have to try all Z in L_2(C, Z) and L_2(Z, Q) and in this case Z can only be R and you get L_3(C, Q) = {C -> R -> Q}.  For other pairs, you might have an empty L_3(X, Y), or there could be many paths of length 3 from X to Y.
However you have to be careful here when building the paths here since some of them must be rejected because they have cycles.  If a path has twice the same node, it is rejected.

Then you build L_4(X, Y) for all pairs by combining all paths L_2(X, Z) and L_3(Z, Y) while looping over all possible values for Z.  You still remove paths with cycles.

And so on... until you get to L_17576(X, Y).

One worry with this method is that you might run out of memory to store those lists.  Note however that after having computed the L_4's, you can get rid of the L_3's, etc.  Of course you don't want to delete L_3(A, Z) since those paths are valid paths from A to Z.

Implementation detail: you could put L_3(X, Y) in a 17576 x 17576 array, where the element at (X, Y) is is some structure that stores all paths between (X, Y).  However if most elements are empty (no paths), you could use instead a `HashMap<Pair, Set<Path>>`, where `Pair` is just some object that stores (X, Y).  It's not clear to me if most elements of L_3(X, Y) are empty, and if so, if it is also the case for L_4334(X, Y).

Thanks to @Lie Ryan for pointing out this identical [question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/18603/finding-all-paths-on-undirected-graph) on mathoverflow.  My solution is basically the one by MRA; Huang claims it's not valid, but by removing the paths with duplicate nodes, I think my solution is fine.

I guess my solution needs less computations than the brute force approach, however it requires more memory.  So much so that I'm not even sure it is possible on a computer with a reasonable amount of memory.